# how to fix yandex api code leak in twitter bot?

Tags: javascript, node-red

I'm a beginner in programming and I'm developing a bot on node-red in the ibm cloud, and I've had problems with the return of the yandex translation API. It returns part of the api code in the tweets, which is not pleasant at all.

The api of yandex allows the api to return in json or xml, I tried both and I could not solve the problem. The bot in question has other api's in use and I was able to configure them normally, something that does not occur with the result of that, which would be the final result for the tweet to be released.

to send the translation to be made use the following request in a function of node red:

```
var translate =   msg.method ='GET';
              msg.url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr/translate?key= *API KEY* &text=" + recipe + "&lang=pt"
              return [msg,null];]
```

in the next block, and the last one before sending the message, I'm using something like:

```
var yandex= msg.payload;
yandex = 'a' + msg.payload.text;
return msg;
```

and this makes me return something like this in the public tweet

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
< Translation code="200" lang="en-pt"><text>é uma receita com Estilo grego Desfrutar de sua comida!</text>< / T"
```

hope to remove all this code that is being sent to output and only send the translation to the tweet, which is what is inside .
Forgive me code redundancies, but I do not know javascript fully and my college is teaching languages a bit old, like pascal.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the translation without writing a single line of code. This is the power of Node-RED. All you need is to send a properly formatted payload to an `http request node`. In the configuration dialog of this node tick the option `Append msg.payload as query string parameters`. You will get the translation by extracting msg.payload.text.

The payload to send to the `http request` has to be structured as follows:

```
{
    "key": "you key",
    "lang": "en-pt",
    "format": "plain",
    "text": "Life is like a game"
}
```

The code you posted has syntax errors and will not produce the output you want.

I recommend you to study a little bit more Node-RED and ask questions [their forum](https://discourse.nodered.org/) in case you did not understand what is explained above.